# jsPDF page break

Tags: jspdf, page-break, export-to-pdf

I have 2 divs in my page tab1 and tab2.

I would like to export both divs in 1 PDF file with tab1 as the 1st page and tab2 starting from the following page.

Currently the 2nd div appears broken in the exported file hence I would like to have the div appear from the next page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `<!--ADD_PAGE-->` (ADD_PAGE with in commented angular <> braces) from where you want new page.
It works.

Comment: `<!-- ADD_PAGE -->` only works if you're using fromHTML method `pdf.fromHTML();`

Comment: As @gorodezkiy says above. Also pdf.fromHTML appears to be deprecated and is not available in the latest releases.